# use isdigit() macro to parse command line

Tags: c, macros

I have the following code to read an argument from the command line. If the string is in this form hw:1,0 I want to break.

```
gboolean parse_one_option (gint opt, const gchar * arg, GError ** err)
{
    switch (opt) {
    case DEVICE:
        if (!strncmp(arg, "hw:", 3) && isdigit(arg[3]) && arg[4] == ',' && isdigit(arg[5])) {
            char *device = g_strdup (arg);
            break;
        break;
```

The compiler gives me a warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'isdigit' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                    if (!strncmp(arg, "hw:", 3) && isdigit(arg[3]) && arg[4] == ',' && isdigit(arg[5])) {
                                                   ^
```

and another question:

Is correct to use g_strdup in combination with GOptionContext

Comment: When facing `implicit declaration warning` try to look for proper includes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `#include <ctype.h>` for this function/macro to be available.

Comment: I think `isdigit()` is a **function** in `ctype.h` as [given here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/isdigit.html)

Comment: @nishant "they may be implemented as macros", as they usually are.